# C++ linking error upon using "string"

Tags: c++, macos, linker, g++, clang

I'm working on a hobby side mini project in C++ and I have the following error upon running my binary.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      recv_line(int) in networking.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have a file networking.cpp which has uses an instance of "std::string". I have the following contents inside my networking.h

```
#ifndef _NETWORKING_H
#define _NETWORKING_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define DELIMITER '\n'

std::string recv_line(int sockfd);
#endif
```

Inside networking.cpp I merely have :-

```
std::string recv_line(int sockfd) {
return "";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]

I'm making the file as follows :-

```
% cat Makefile
CXX=g++

blah: main networking
    $(CXX) main.o networking.o -o blah -v
main:
    $(CXX) -c main.cpp
networking:
    $(CXX) -c networking.cpp
% make
```

The version of g++ seems to be :-

```
% g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: How do you compile and how do you link your program? Show the relevant commands please! And which version of `g++` ?

Comment: Added that information, thanks

Comment: Your `Makefile` is ill-formed: probably `CC` should often be replaced by `$(CC)` and you really should use `CXX` instead of `CC`; BTW, passing `-Wall -g` to `g++` is very useful!

Comment: Ive added it but the errors seem to persist

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_NETWORKING_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link `stdc++` library to your program. This you can do here.

```
$(CC) main.o networking.o -o blah -v -lstdc++.
```

Error here shows that `libstdc++` is not being linked your program.

Also, in make file, use `$(CC)` instead of `CC`.

Comment: A correctly configured `g++` should *implicitly* link `-lstdc++` (and that library depends upon the compiler). On Linux, there is no need to tell `g++`  about `-lstdc++` ; BTW, this is one of the differences between `gcc`  and `g++` ; both are able to compile C++ files `*.cpp` or `*.cc` but link them differently!